# What are the reason boost async_send can get stuck?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a simple TCP client sending data to an endpoint.
I use boost.asio and occasionally the [async_send](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_send/overload2.html) gets stuck - control never returns.

Below is a pseudo code of what is happening (please assume we have an `io_service` running to pick up handlers and the socket connect has happened successfully as an initial setup)

```cpp
   some::lock_free::queue<string> q_; // e.g. moody_camel 
   uint64_t max_q_size = 10000;

   main(){
    string str ="hello";
    uint64_t size= 5;

     while(true){
        // async_wait using steady timer for 10ms
        addToQueue(&str,size);
     }
   }

   bool addToQueue(string& data, uint64_t size){
       if (max_q_size > (cur_q_size + size)) {
           cout<< "queue capacity at max"<<endl;
           return false;
       } else {
           q_.enqueue(data);
           cur_q_size+=size;
           return true;
       }
   } 

   dequeueAndSend(){
      
      string& d_;
      for(auto popped=q_.pop(d_);;popped=q_.pop(d_)){
         if(!popped){
        // async_wait using steady timer for 10ms
         } else {
           sendData(d_);
         }
      }
   }

   sendData(string& buf){

       boost::asio::yield_context yc;
       boost::system::error_code ec;
       
       cout<< "Start pushing data"<<endl;
       
       socket_.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(buf), yc[ec]);  
       
       cout<< "Done pushing data"<<endl;

       return ec;
    }
```

this works flawlessly but occasionally during a restart (assume no issues with the socket on the other end) it is observed that we never send any data, we never get `Done pushing data` after i get `Starting pushing data` - what could the reasons be ? I also want to understand what's happening behind the scenes here. Thank you.

For now, i'm wrapping this send operation using a deadline timer as below example as a workaround.
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp

Comment: That is interesting `async_send` should return immediately always. It shouldn't block ever. The only case I can imagine it blocks is when other thread keeps lock on `io_context` and never releases it. So when it happens again, pause your program in debugger and check call stacks of other threads. Maybe you have a dead lock in your code.

Comment: @MarekR, it doesn't block but the strand is paused until the async operation is completed right ? and resumed once done by the `io_service`. Here, it is never resumed - this is what i meant by 'never returns'. Maybe i should word is better.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify any doubts. Comment is bad place to do it. Question should be self sufficient. I understood your question that call to `async_send` blocks. When I read your question again after your comment I still understand it same way. Please fix your question.

Comment: It probably means your service runs out of work. This could very easily happen here if you have too many separate io_service objects. As always, we can only answer question when there's a minimal code snippet included.

Comment: By the way "it doesn't block but the strand is paused [...] right" - not quite. The strand is occupied during the completion handler. It acts like a mutex to prevent concurrent access to shared objects. "Pausing" implies blocking, which is the opposite of what Asio's async interface achieves. Of course, there **is no strand** because we see no code. Which is why we can't point out the error.

Comment: @sehe added pseudo code. thanks for the help.

Comment: @MarekR, edited, thanks for the help.

Comment: would the snippet attached suffice ? @sehe